# Check for new payments from a recurring billing on Paypal

Tags: php, api, paypal, nvp

I create recurring payment profile in Paypal using NVP(CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile).

Tell me please, how can I check new payments using api requests?

I need it to continue the billing plan for user on my own website.

I have "PROFILEID", "TOKEN", "TRANSACTIONID".

Website was created using php.

Answer (score 0):

Just add new field into your transaction table flag_is_new and set it at default 0. After that at the end of each checking for new transactions update this field to 1.

Comment: But i dont know how i can check for new transactions. It is my question.

Comment: You must store each transaction into your database. There is no api method to check for new transactions

Comment: But how can i do it if it is recurring payment profile?